# Code Coverage and Lines of Code are displayed as '-' in sonarqube console

Tags: c#, azure, sonarqube, nunit, azure-pipelines

I am using azure devops for running a test and trying to integrate sonarqube with it.The issue i am facing is that in the summary part of azure pipeline i am able to view code coverage as 22% but in the sonarqube console i am only able to view code coverage as '-'.There is a warning message that i am seeing when i run 'Run Code Analysis' task in pipeline.
The warning message is WARN: The Code Coverage report doesn't contain any coverage data for the included files.
[Please find the image to view the code coverage displayed in azure pipeline][1]

This is the yaml for dot test task

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test'
  inputs:
  command: test
  projects: '**/*Test*.csproj'
  arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"  '
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

This is the yaml for copy files task that i am doing right after the dot test task
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.WorkFolder)\_temp'
    TargetFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'

Please find the yaml file for Prepare analysis on sonarqube task
displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'CDA-Sonarqube'
    projectKey: Test
    projectName: Test
    extraProperties: sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths

Any help is appreciated.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbZfW.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WARN: The Code Coverage report doesn't contain any coverage data for the included files.
```

For troubleshooting hints, please refer to https://docs.sonarqube.org/x/CoBh , the .coverage file will be convert to coveragexml during sonarqube end analysis task

```
Run Unit Tests and Save Results in file "NUnitResults.xml"

packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0\tools \ nunit3-console.exe --result=NUnitResults.xml "NUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\NUnitTestProject1.dll"

or, for older NUnit 2

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NUnit 2.6.4\bin \nunit-console.exe /result=NUnitResults.xml "NUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\NUnitTestProject1.dll"
```

Meanwhile,there is a workaround explained in the [VSTS extension documentation in "Analysing a .NET solution"](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-azure-devops/): in the Additional Properties text area, add the following property:

```
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=**/*.coveragexml
```

You can also refer to these cases([case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226358/publish-test-coverage-of-multiple-net-core-projects-from-azure-devops-to-sonarq) , [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48945031/sonarqube-code-coverage-from-vsts)) for details.

Here is a [blog](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/10/11/configure-code-coverage-for-dotnet-core-2-0-based-applications-using-sonarqube-and-azure-devops/) about configuring Code Coverage for Dotnet Core based applications using SonarQube and Azure DevOps .

Comment: In which task should i convert .coverage file to coveragexml

Comment: You can use CodeCoverage.exe tool to convert .coverage to .xml file.

Answer (score 0):

By default the test result files are in temp folder, try to copy files through Copy File task, then the .coverage file will be analysis and generate coveragexml file.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2

  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.sourcesdirectory)\TestResults'

  inputs:

    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)'

    TargetFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)\TestResults'
```

On the other hand, you can refer to this article to call CodeCoverage.exe:
[Configure Code Coverage for Dotnet Core 2.0 based applications using SonarQube and Azure DevOps](https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/10/11/configure-code-coverage-for-dotnet-core-2-0-based-applications-using-sonarqube-and-azure-devops/)